# ASP.NET Identity / OAuth: How can I restrict the granted privileges to allow nothing but just to authenticate?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

When I see [OAuth samples for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.benday.com/2014/02/25/walkthrough-asp-net-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/) it looks like they always grant some kind of privileges to the client application:

[image]

I don't want *any* privileges to be granted. I just want a user to be authenticated.

How can I set this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OAuth 2.0 without any privileges (or: scopes) does not make sense (unless a default scope is always assumed by the Authorization Server). It seems that you're looking for user authentication, which is not a function of OAuth 2.0 per se. You need an extension such as OpenID Connect, in which case you would provide only the "openid" scope in the authentication request.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me! -- NB: Your answer lead me to this web page: (http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/22/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-and-identityserver/) which adds some more detail.